# How to use springbatch without mapping a line into a domain object

Tags: spring-batch

Normally, reading from a csv file then writing into database, we map every line into a POJO(domain object). But how to do this when the csv file changes? That means, there are many csv files with different format, and I do not want to write POJO for each of them.

I can think two ways to handle it. First generate POJO class dynamically, but how? Second, use `PassThroughFieldSetMapper` and `PassThroughItemProcessor`, but how to set parameter for SQL in `JdbcBatchItemWriter`?

Answer (score 1):

You can make this relatively configurable, but at the end of the day, you'll ultimately need to map the fields in the file to the columns of the database *somewhere*.

You could start with something like this and then figure out how to dynamically define your `fieldMap` bean... You could also take it a step further and include data types for each column in the database.

```
<bean id="csvReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters['FILENAME']}" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="#{fieldMap.keySet()}" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughFieldSetMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql" ref="sqlString" />
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
        <bean class="org.sample.sql.FieldSetItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sqlString" class="org.sample.factory.SqlFactoryBean">
    <property name="table" value="MY_TABLE" />
    <property name="schema" value="${my.schema}" />
    <property name="fieldMap" ref="fieldMap" />
</bean>

<util:map id="fieldMap">
    <entry key="firstName" value="FIRST_NAME" />
    <entry key="lastName" value="LAST_NAME" />
    <entry key="email" value="EMAIL" />
    <entry key="birthDate" value="BIRTH_DATE" />
</util:map>
```

**FactoryBean**

```
public class SqlFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<String> {

    private String table;
    private String schema;
    private Map<String, String> fieldMap;

    @Override
    public String getObject() throws Exception {
        Assert.isTrue((fieldMap != null) && (fieldMap.size() > 0));
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO " + schema + "." + table + " ");

        final Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = fieldMap.entrySet().iterator();
        Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
        final StringBuilder columnBuilder = new StringBuilder("(" + entry.getValue());
        final StringBuilder paramBuilder = new StringBuilder("(" + entry.getKey());
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            entry = iterator.next();
            columnBuilder.append("," + entry.getValue());
            paramBuilder.append("," + entry.getKey());
        }
        columnBuilder.append(")");
        paramBuilder.append(")");

        sb.append(columnBuilder.toString());
        sb.append(" values ");
        sb.append(paramBuilder.toString());

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider**

```
public class FieldSetItemSqlParameterSourceProvider 
                    implements ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<FieldSet> {
    @Override
    public SqlParameterSource createSqlParameterSource(FieldSet item) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Entry<Object, Object> entry : item.getProperties().entrySet()) {
            map.put((String) entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return new MapSqlParameterSource(map);
    }
}
```